# Mediawiki CSS not loading on hosted server (IIS)

Tags: php, mysql, css, iis, mediawiki

I am trying to get mediawiki hosted via intranet on WindowsServer2012r2.  I have installed mediawiki, php7, and mysql 5.x via Web platform installer.  Once all were installed and setup I was able to connect both locally and via networked computers to mediawiki. I noticed however that the CSS for mediaWiki was not being executed.  I have gone through the steps provided @ [Styles not displaying](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Load.php) and [Manual:Errors and symptoms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms) but could not resolve the issue. The browser console shows the below issue.

Running load.php in the browser returns this error:

```
checkUrlExtension() ) { return; } // Respond to resource loading request. // foo()->bar() syntax is not supported in PHP4, and this file needs to *parse* in PHP4. $configFactory = ConfigFactory::getDefaultInstance(); $resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader( $configFactory->makeConfig( 'main' ), LoggerFactory::getInstance( 'resourceloader' ) ); $resourceLoader->respond( new ResourceLoaderContext( $resourceLoader, $wgRequest ) ); Profiler::instance()->setTemplated( true ); $mediawiki = new MediaWiki(); $mediawiki->doPostOutputShutdown( 'fast' );
```

Just to confirm: I updated the .htaccess file in the mywiki/img folder.   Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does the code you posted comes from? Where did you copied that? It's included in the lod.php file, but this aren't all lines. If your wiki does not have any styles, please check (with the browser console), what happens with the load.php requests and what error messages are returend there. Also: What does your server side logging say?

Comment: which server log are you referring to? also, would you be able to confirm which .htaccess file I am suppose to edit? thanks much

Comment: Let us check another thing before that :) Are you using MediaWiki 1.26.2 with Vector (from the official download link?)? If so, I think the problem might be related to https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T119934 can you check, if your wiki (webserver) has write access to the temporary directory of your server (usually /tmp or the value of $wgCacheDirectory, if set in the LocalSettings.php)?

Comment: As i am fairly new to IIS and windows server would you be able to provide me some helpful steps? I have cleared the "read only" button on the Windows Temp folder but that does not seem to have done it.

Comment: Oh, ähm, sorry, I never ever used IIS (at least not on a basis that I can say "yes, I can help you"). Maybe you should ask in a better stackexchange site how to solve this write to temp dir problem :)